# ionic cordova run android not working. Giving error for strip-final-newline

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to use Background Geolocation in ionic.
When I run `ionic cordova run android` it is giving me following error:

```
> cordova.cmd build android
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: ERROR: EXCEPTION: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\node_modules\strip-final-newline\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\node_modules\strip-final-newline\index.js from C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\node_modules\strip-final-newline\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\node_modules\strip-final-newline\package.json.

Unable to load Platform API from C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:
Must use import to load ES Module: C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\node_modules\strip-final-newline\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\node_modules\strip-final-newline\index.js from C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\execa\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\node_modules\strip-final-newline\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\node_modules\strip-final-newline\package.json.

> native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
[native-run] No hardware devices found, attempting emulator...
[native-run] ERR_NO_TARGET: No targets devices/emulators available. Cannot create AVD because there is no suitable API installation. Use --sdk-info to reveal missing packages and other issues.
[native-run]
[native-run]    More details for this error may be available online:
[native-run]
[native-run]    https://github.com/ionic-team/native-run/wiki/Android-Errors
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

        native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-d... exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

After installing `npm install strip-final-newline` I am finding above error Could you please help?

Comment: why is your project in htdocs?

Comment: Could be any place? I kept as it is easier for me.

Comment: it should not be in htdocs.  run command `ionic info` and add output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

I uninstalled strip-final-newline and then downgraded to 2.0.0 with

```
npm install strip-final-newline@2.0.0
```